# My observer is not notified on the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification?

Tags: keyboard-events

I am looking at an implementation of a Tree View which I would like to use in my app but to my surprise, the UIViewController does not respond to the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification when the keyboard hides?

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And then of course:

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Wanted to do something here...");
}
```

I am pulling my hairs out as I can't find a possible reason as to why this is.
The full project can be downloaded from: http://code.google.com/p/pstreegraph/
and I extended the leafs of the tree view with a UITextField so that I can edit the leafs of the tree view.

Thanks for your help!
Koen